# windows bash ifconfig не работает

Tags: windows, bash

```
farex@DESKTOP-3U5V5MP:~$ ifconfig
Команда 'ifconfig' доступна в '/sbin/ifconfig'
Команда не может быть найдена, потому что '/sbin' не включена в переменную окружения  PATH
Вероятно, причиной является отсутствие прав администратора у вашей учетной записи.
ifconfig: команда не найдена
farex@DESKTOP-3U5V5MP:~$ sudo ifconfig
sudo: unable to resolve host DESKTOP-3U5V5MP
Внимание: невозможно открыть /proc/net/dev (Нет такого файла или каталога). Ограниченный вывод.
farex@DESKTOP-3U5V5MP:~$
```

В чем может быть проблема?

```
root@DESKTOP-3U5V5MP:/home/farex# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# NOTE: the primary ethernet device is defined in
# /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

root@DESKTOP-3U5V5MP:/home/farex#
```

Comment: Укажите в какой оболочке вы используете bash. Причины ошибки недонзначно указаны - "отсутствие прав администратора".

Comment: Windows 10 bash (ubuntu)

Comment: Что это за симбиоз? Дайте ссылку.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/280560/

Comment: Я предполагаю, что и не должно работать. `ifconfig` - довольно системная утилита, которая тесно взаимодействует с сетевой подсистемой ядра. В винде и в линуксе всё наверняка очень сильно отличается, поэтому `ifconfig` и не портирован.

Comment: в системе он присутствует... вообще не очень понятно как работает сеть.

Comment: @yeputons, у меня `ifconfig` присутствует и вроде как работает. Ничего специально не настраивал. http://i.imgur.com/5i2AoKg.png

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев какая версия Windows? Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes) пишут, что ifconfig начал работать только в Build 14965.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для проверки текущего состояния сетевых настроек НЕ нужны права супер юзера, другими словамии никаких sudo, su, sudo su НЕ нужно ;_)

Проверяем, что у нас в переменной окружения PATH, так как первое сообщение нас туда отсылает:

```
~$ echo $PATH
```

Есть ли вообще команда ifconfig в системе:

```
~$ /usr/bin/which ifconfig
~$ /usr/bin/find / -type f -name "ifconfig"
```

Если есть ifconfig, но нет в PATH:

```
~$ /usr/bin/ifconfig
~$ /usr/sbin/ifconfig
~$ /usr/*/ifconfig
```

Или добавить к PATH:

```
~$ export PATH=$PATH+":/usr/sbin/"
```

Или нафиг все сторонние прграммы, читаем напрямую из системы (для экспертов):

```
~# /usr/sbin/find /proc/net -exec cat {} \;
```

Или если нужны настройки сети можно попробовать новй инструмент - ip (пакет iprout2):

```
~$ ip address
```

Или прямо на Win - ipconfig:

```
>win$ ipconfig
```

- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-iproute2.org
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Variable-Index.html#Variable-Index
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#index-PATH
- https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-dir-net.html